# Probability of timer overlap

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let's say I have two timers with uniform random timeouts in the range $(a,b)$. When one timer goes off it needs to communicate to the other timer which takes $c \ll a,b$ time and perform an operation $\varepsilon \ll c$ before resetting it. However, we do not want the second timer going off as we do the operation (before that is fine). What is the chance of that happening? (Timers are independent and are assumed to start at the same time)

I believe this can be represented as

$$t_1 \sim U(a,b)$$
$$t_2 \sim U(a,b)$$

$$ p(t_1+c < t_2 < t_1+c+\varepsilon) $$

But I have no idea how to compute it given $a,b,c,\varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

If the distribution is uniform, you just take the ratio of the time intervals, so the probability is $\frac {\varepsilon}b$.  $c$ does not matter as long as $a \lt b+\varepsilon$ so the whole interval of interest fits within $b$.

Comment: Why does $a$ not appear in the probability? I was expecting $b-a$ term somewhere

Comment: Let $a$ be one minute, $b$ be ten minutes, and $\varepsilon$ be a second.  You are worried about $b$ going off at some time in a particular second, which is does with probability $\frac 1{600}$.  If $a$ becomes five minutes it doesn't change anything.  The second of concern could now come any time in five minutes, but the chance $b$ goes off in the next second after $a$ does is unchanged.